# How to add to existing numbers? C++

Tags: c++, nodes, singly-linked-list

I hope you all are having a wonderful day. Just to give a little context, I am trying to make a Mancala game in C++. The case is that I wanted to add to each number when a user gives an index. So for example, if the user types in 10 for the game of

```
  04 04 04 04 04 04
00                  00
  04 04 04 04 04 04
           ^^
```

Then that will be the number indicated by the arrows. I wanted to create code that will add one to each corresponding number in the game and result in this output:

```
   04 04 04 04 04 05
00                   01
   04 04 04 00 05 0
```

Comment: There's a lot of code here, and I'm not sure I understand the actual question. Can you narrow it down to the function that isn't working, what it's supposed to do, and what it's doing instead? I don't know what you mean by "4 4 4 4 4 4 0 4 4 4 4 4 4 0 to: 5 4 4 4 4 4 0 4 4 4 0 5 5 1".

Comment: Absolutely! thank you for responding. I wanted to add to each number when a user gives an index. So for example, if the user types in 10 for the game of         
 4 4 4 4 4 4 0 4 4 4 4 4 4 0, then that'll be 4th to last number - the zeroes are the scores. What will happen is +1(of four points) will go into each number resulting in: 5 4 4 4 4 4 0 4 4 4 0 5 5 1...."1" was changed because the user dropped a point into their side

Comment: @beginnercoderuh I'm sorry but I still don't get your problem. How does 10 translate to `04` being chosen? And then what do you want to add 1 to? Why do only 2 `04` become `05` and the pointed-to `04` become `00`? Do we need to read up on the Mancala game? Also, what's that single-digit 0 in the last row? Please read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so that we can can help you.

Comment: Hint:  modulo (remainer) operator.  The board kinda looks circular (in fact, you could make it circular).

Comment: Hint:  if a pod (bowl) contains 5 seeds, that means the seed count of the current bowl is zero and the seed count of the next 5 seeds will be incremented.  You *could* make them into a linked list.

Comment: In your 2nd diagram, how did the slot after `05` become `0`?  What rules are you playing by?

Comment: What have you tried so far?  StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592), as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, and show a specific roadblock you're running into with a [mcve]. For more information, please see [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's use a circular array to represent the board.
Each side has 6 slots, plus their "winnings" slot.

```
static const unsigned int MAX_SLOTS = 14u;
```

In my understanding of the game, a move is made by taking the contents of a slot and redistributing them (one per slot) in a clockwise or counter clockwise manner.

```
std::vector<int> board(MAX_SLOTS) = 
{ 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0,
  4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 4, 0};

void player_move(int starting_index, std::vector<int>& gameboard)
{
    const int quantity = gameboard[index];
    const unsigned int board_capacity = gameboard.size();
    gameboard[index] = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < quantity; ++i)
    {
        const int position = (starting_index + 1 + i) % board_capacity;
        ++gameboard[position];
    }
}
```

The above code only performs a player's move.  The next step is to analyze the board for removal of beans, and possible additional moves.

The key *trick* for a circular array is the use of the `%` operator.

**Edit:  Changing direction**
You can change the direction of the distribution by changing the `position` calculation:

```
const int position = (board_capacity + starting_index - i - 1) % board_position;
```